# Undefined Variable in Qt Creator C++ using OpenCV

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, compiler-errors, qt-creator

I'm facing problem in my qt creator, here is the issue that shown by Qt Creator:

> D:\Kuliah\Semester 5\IF431316 PECI\Qt Project File\Sobel\main.cpp:39: error: undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)`
>   D:\Kuliah\Semester 5\IF431316 PECI\Qt Project File\Sobel\main.cpp:60: error: undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(cv::String const&, int)`
>   D:\Kuliah\Semester 5\IF431316 PECI\Qt Project File\Sobel\main.cpp:61: error: undefined reference to `cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&)`
>       D:\Kuliah\Semester 5\IF431316 PECI\Qt Project File\Sobel\main.cpp:64: error: undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(cv::String const&, int)`
>       D:\Kuliah\Semester 5\IF431316 PECI\Qt Project File\Sobel\main.cpp:65: error: undefined reference to `cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&)`
>       D:\Kuliah\Semester 5\IF431316 PECI\Qt Project File\build-Sobel-Desktop-Debug\debug\main.o:-1: In function `ZN2cv6StringC1EPKc':
>       collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status

This is my `.pro` file that contain library, I've trying add some libraries as suggested by many members, but nothing happen at all, it's getting worse

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += C:\\opencv\\build\\include \
INCLUDEPATH += C:\\opencv\\sources\\include \

LIBS += -LC:\\opencv\\sources\Built_with_Qt\\debug\\lib \
  -lopencv_calib3d231d \
  -lopencv_contrib231d \
  -lopencv_core231d \
  -lopencv_features2d231d \
  -lopencv_flann231d \
  -lopencv_gpu231d \
  -lopencv_highgui231d \
  -lopencv_imgproc231d \
  -lopencv_legacy231d \
  -lopencv_ml231d \
  -lopencv_objdetect231d \
  -lopencv_ts231d \
  -lopencv_video231d
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong direction of slashes. Qt is using Linux style directory separators even if it is windows platform.

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/opencv/build/include \
INCLUDEPATH += C:/opencv/sources/include \

LIBS += -LC:/opencv/sources/Built_with_Qt/debug/lib \
  -lopencv_calib3d231d \
  -lopencv_contrib231d \
  -lopencv_core231d \
  -lopencv_features2d231d \
  -lopencv_flann231d \
  -lopencv_gpu231d \
  -lopencv_highgui231d \
  -lopencv_imgproc231d \
  -lopencv_legacy231d \
  -lopencv_ml231d \
  -lopencv_objdetect231d \
  -lopencv_ts231d \
  -lopencv_video231d
```

Another problem I can see is that you are using `namedWindow`. If you have a Qt then you should not use it since Qt provide on windows which are much more handy.

Apparently you are using some custom build of OpenCV. Are you sure that it wasn't configured in such way the unneeded for Qt functions were deactivated?